# ¿Cómo elimino un objeto de un arreglo en Java?

Tags: java, poo

Soy nuevo en esto, por lo que el código fue hecho para principiantes a modo de ejemplo. Se nos estaba mostrando el uso de arreglos y POO en java NetBeans, en este ejemplo hay alguna forma de eliminar un registro previamente agregado? Usando `static private void Eliminar()`? Debe preguntar al usuario si desea eliminarlo escribiendo s/n, pero en caso de que la respuesta sea 's' no sé como indicarle que elimine el objeto en que se encontró en esa posición. No sé si habré hecho bien la estructura de `static private void Eliminar()` o si hay una mejor forma de hacerlo. Pensé en usar .remove pero tengo entendido que se usa con ArrayList y este no es el caso, o me equivoco? Estoy algo confundido.

```
    package registroveterinario;

    import Clases.Registro;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class RegistroVeterinario {
     public static Registro registro[] = new Registro[3];
     public static int conta = 0;
     public static Scanner Entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            
     static private void agregar(){
       Registro _registro = new Registro();
       Entrada.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Digite el nombre del dueño : ");
       _registro.setNombreDueño(Entrada.nextLine());
       System.out.print("Digite la cedula : ");
       _registro.setCedula(Entrada.nextInt());
       Entrada.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Digite el nombre de la mascota : ");
       _registro.setNombreMascota(Entrada.nextLine());
  
       registro[conta] = _registro;
       conta++;
     }

     static private void Eliminar(){
          Entrada.nextLine();
          System.out.print("Nombre de la persona: ");
          String NombreDueño;
          NombreDueño = Entrada.nextLine();
          char resp;
          boolean aux = false;
          for (int i=0;i<conta;i++){
               if(registro[i].getNombreDueño().contains(NombreDueño)){
            
               System.out.print("Desea eliminar el registro (s/n)");
               resp = Entrada.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
               if(resp == 's'){
                
                  System.out.print("Registro eliminado");
          
                   aux = true;
                 }
              }
          }
          if(aux==false){
              System.out.print("El registro no existe");  
          }   
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {
     int opcion=0;
       String cad = "======Registro======\n";
              cad+= "1. Agregar\n";
              cad+= "3. Eliminar\n";
              cad+= "6. Salir\n";
              cad+= "Digite opción: ";             
       do{
          System.out.print(cad);
          opcion = Entrada.nextInt();
          switch(opcion){
              case 1: agregar();break;
              case 3: Eliminar();break;
          }
       }while(opcion<6);
      } 
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes cambiar el tamaño de un array, si lo has declarado con longitud 3, ése será el tamaño que tenga. La forma de borrar un objeto, en tu caso, sería asignar `null` a la posición que quieres borrar:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < registro.length; i++){
          if (registro[i] != null &&
                  registro[i].getNombreDueño().contains(NombreDueño)){
              System.out.print("Desea eliminar el registro (s/n)");
              resp = Entrada.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
              if(resp == 's'){
                  registro[i] = null;
                  System.out.print("Registro eliminado");
                  aux = true;
              }
          }
      }
```